# Notepad++ extended replace ^ with preceding line

Tags: regex, notepad++

How can I replace every line that starts with a "," in regex "^," in notepad++ with its preceding line.

```
 A
 ,B,C,D
 1
 ,2,3,4
 E
 ,F,G,H,
```

When replaced I should get

```
A,B,C,D
1,2,3,4
E,F,G,H
```

Comment: All lines other than the first also have a leading space, right? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Thanks for the reply and as for the  ,'s they dont have a leading space. Searching for a ^, gets all the lines beginning with a , now Im stuck at getting the preceding line . Hence replace with will look like "preceedingline,"

Comment: Try `^\h*(.*)\R\h*,` and replace with `\1,`. Or `\R,` -> `,`.

Comment: Or, `\R\h*,` -> `,`.

Comment: The expression with \1, did the trick. Could you add that as an answer. Thanks

Comment: Posted with a bit of explanation, please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
^\h*(.*)\R\h*,
```

And replace with `\1,`. The regex will match a line and capture it into Group 1 (with `.*`) without leading horizontal whitespace (it is matched with `\h*` but is not *captured* since it is outside the unescaped parentheses in the beginning of the pattern) and then will match any newline sequence with `\R` and then zero or more horizontal whitespace with `\h*` and a literal `,`.

With the replacement pattern, we restore the previous line and just add a comma.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\v+(\,)` and replace it with `\1`

The first will find any vertical whitespaces (mostly newline and carriage return) followed by a comma and then replace it with the comma.